# Hmisc::latex with sapply and htest class produce many tables

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

I can't get table with `Hmisc::latex` and `sapply` function. `latex` return many tables. I would like to use a `Hmisc::latex` because it more flexible configurable.

Steps to reproduce problem:

```
library(xtable)
library(Hmisc)
library(nortest)
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100)
norm.x <- sapply(x, sf.test)[1:2,]
latex(norm.x, file="", dec=2)
xtable(norm.x) # In contrast xtable produce pretty output
```

**Edit:**

Solution (thanks to Sven Hohenstein):

```
library(Hmisc)
library(nortest)
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100)
norm.x <- sapply(x, function(z) unlist(sf.test(z)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))
latex(norm.x, file="", dec=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the object `norm.x` returned by `sapply(x, sf.test)[1:2,]` with the functions `unlist` and `matrix`.

```
norm.x <- matrix(unlist(norm.x), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("w", "p-value")))
```

---

The complete code:

```
library("xtable")
library("Hmisc")
library("nortest")
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(100)))
norm.x <- sapply(x, sf.test)[1:2,]
norm.x <- matrix(unlist(norm.x), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("w", "p-value")))
latex(norm.x, file="", dec=2)
xtable(norm.x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I transpose 'norm.x' because with it contain many column. With transpose variant 'dec=3' option is not work.